# Why do MRU cache replacement and LRU policy perform same on Sniper Multicore simulator when its cache_size =8192KB of L3 ?

Tags: simulation

In *Sniper Multicore  Simulator* for these benchmarks **gcc, bzip, lbm** etc i ran *simulation* for *cache_size*=8192kB **MRU** and **LRU** performs same i.e.  Same identical output file but it shouldn't be equal as MRU and LRU are different policies but when i reduces *cache_size* =512KB then these performs different.  So I think its because of size MRU and LRU perform same on these benchmarks. But why does it happen??  Anyone can explain..   Thanks

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: Which code do u want?  Code for these policies? Because the code is available in sniper multi core packages..